# text-decoration won't work for hover in hyperlink (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I've started to learn HTML and a little CSS. I have a problem in desiging my hyperlink. The "text-decoration" property won't work for hyperlink while hovered. here is my codes:
[my HTML and CSS codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luHzV.png)
And I will be thankful if you give an helpful advice through HTML and CSS learning.

Comment: You need to always put your code in your question as a [mcve], not an image

Comment: Also please expand on what 'wont work' means.

Comment: Not solution-related but a couple great sandboxes to test HTML + CSS (and use as a template in a question where users can run your code) are : https://jsfiddle.net/ and https://codepen.io/ .. This way you can create a fiddle and use it in your question. There's also the StackOverflow built-in feature for this as well.

Comment: You might be following an ancient tutorial because your file has .htm extension.

Comment: Kindly explain 'wont work' with a possible screenshot or explanation of what you see on the screen. This will help people to identify problems and to answer quickly. Also kindly do a spell check and Capitalisation check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a semi-colon `;` on line 19.

Helpful Links:

- https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/responsive-web-design/
- https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Semi colon is missing in your code#

> a:hover{color:rgba(195,255,0,0.8);
> text-decoration:underline;}

Comment: Suggestion : use code fences instead of blockquotes